# iOS : UITableView reloaddata do not reload all cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

Here is my scenario,my View Controller receive data after a modal segue,i called reloaddata method in viewWillAppear.I mean to create a tableView that only display 4 rows at most.First row show the same content.If data is more than 4, table View only display the first two datas,the last row display is there any more data.If data is less than 4,table View just display first row plus data rows.
Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (_assmebleModel.cityId.count < 4) {
        return _assmebleModel.cityId.count + 1;
    }else {
        return 4;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellId = @"CityBarCellId";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
        if (0 == indexPath.row) {
            UIImageView *markerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Map Marker"]];
            markerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 30, 30);

            UILabel *cityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 15, 80, 20)];
            cityLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cityLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cityLabel.text = @"编辑地点";
            [cell addSubview:markerImageView];
            [cell addSubview:cityLabel];
        }
        if (0 != indexPath.row && _assmebleModel.cityId.count < 4) {
            UIImageView *markerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marker"]];
            markerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 30, 30);

            UILabel *cityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 15, 80, 20)];
            cityLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cityLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            WeatherInfoModel *infoModel = _assmebleModel.cityId[indexPath.row - 1];
            cityLabel.text = infoModel.cityName;
            [cell addSubview:markerImageView];
            [cell addSubview:cityLabel];
        }
        if (0 != indexPath.row && 3 != indexPath.row && _assmebleModel.cityId.count >= 4) {
            UIImageView *markerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marker"]];
            markerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 30, 30);

            UILabel *cityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 15, 80, 20)];
            cityLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cityLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            WeatherInfoModel *infoModel = _assmebleModel.cityId[indexPath.row - 1];
            cityLabel.text = infoModel.cityName;
            [cell addSubview:markerImageView];
            [cell addSubview:cityLabel];
        }
        if (3 == indexPath.row && _assmebleModel.cityId.count >= 4) {
            UIImageView *markerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"More"]];
            markerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 30, 30);
            UIImageView *arrowImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Expand Arrow"]];
            arrowImageView.frame = CGRectMake(110, 5, 30, 30);

            UILabel *cityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 15, 80, 20)];
            cityLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cityLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"显示其他%lu个项目",(unsigned long)(_assmebleModel.cityId.count - 3)];
            [cell addSubview:arrowImageView];
            [cell addSubview:markerImageView];
            [cell addSubview:cityLabel];
        }
```

I add data one at a time,every time i add a data,it called viewDidAppear.I thought tableView update every cell cause of i called reloaddata.But it appear not,it seem that reloaddata only update the add new one.And when my data is more than 4, program will execute the second If,my last cell do not display right.

I am totally confused,someone help me please,thanks a bunch.

Comment: So, if you manage to dequeue a cell you just use it, without setting any values into it???

Comment: I think your problem is that you're doing everything inside the if(!cell) clause. If a cell is reused, none of that code will be executed.

Comment: @HotLicks oops...there is return cell at last of the method,i do not post it

Comment: @rdelmar I check my cell identity and i create view in code entirely ,i am postive cell is not reused , and i insert NSLog in code , it appear program execute first and second if.Last two if is never executed.

Comment: You clearly don't understand cell reuse in UITableView.  Find a good tutorial.